# Concept of Absolute Thermodynamic Activity

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

In the textbook Electrochemical Systems by Newman and Alyea, Chapter 14: The definition of some thermodynamic functions, chemical potential of component (ionic or neutral) is written as a function of absolute activity: $$\mu_i=RT\ln \lambda_i \tag{1}$$

where $\lambda_i$ is the absolute activity of the component $i$. This equation is referenced to the Guggenheim: Thermodynamics textbook. I checked this textbook, but it didn't really resolve my questions.

Author claims that absolute activity allows us to define chemical potential without reference to the standard state, as it can be seen by the equation 1. This means that absolute activity is independent on the choice of the standard state.

What I know from thermodynamics is that activity is defined as a quantity which allows us to express chemical potential for real systems in the same mathematical form as for ideal systems. Chemical potential for real systems is logarithmic function of activity as it is a logarithmic function of pressure, mole fraction, concentration etc. for ideal systems.

In the most general form, activity is defined as: $$a_i = \frac {f_i}{f_i^⦵} \tag {2}$$

where $f_i$ is the fugacity of the component in the system and $f_i^⦵$ is the standard state fugacity of the component.

Definition of activity is fundamentally tied to the chemical potential and its definition equation can also be written as: $$ \mu_i = \mu_i^⦵ + RT\ln \frac {f_i}{f_i^⦵} = \mu_i^⦵ + RT\ln a_i \tag {3} $$

My question is:

Concept of absolute activity doesn't make sense to me. Activity by definition expresses how much is a component thermodynamically active RELATIVE to the standard state. This is why equation 2 is written as a ratio and why in equation 3, standard state chemical potential $\mu_i^⦵$ shows up.

Given that, I don't understand equation 1 and where is it derived from as we can see a difference comparing equations 1 and 3.

Comment: As an aside, electrochemical books don't do justice in their chapters about thermodynamics.  Even Newman's book suffers from this. However, I remind you that the electrochemical potential (Newman doesn't like this term) is a **definition**. And as such, it is **arbitrary** but the goal is to be a practical for everyone to use it. Since you read the chapter, you can even see that Newman spends time dealing with several convenient/unconvenient definitions. You will not find a derivation of Eq. (1). I will try to answer the question when I have more time...

Comment: Yes, but he references this definition to the thermodynamics textbook by Guggenheim. I checked this textbook, but have to say I'm not a huge fan of its explanations regarding chemical potential and activity relationships. It's the only thermo textbook I came across which uses the concept ''absolute activity'' and says that it's independent of the standard state.

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition of the absolute activity provided by [IUPAC](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/A00019)

$\mu_i=RT\ln \lambda_i \tag{1}$

$\mu_i^\circ=RT\ln \lambda_i^\circ \tag{2}$

Therefore,

$\mu_i = \mu_i^\circ + RT\ln  a_i \tag {3}$

becomes

$RT\ln \lambda_i = RT\ln \lambda_i^\circ + RT\ln  a_i \tag {4}$

or

$$ a_i = \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i^\circ} \tag {5}$$

This is equivalent to your equation (2), except that $\lambda_i^\circ$, the value of the absolute activity in the reference standard state (at which $a_i=1$), need not be equivalent to the value of the fugacity in that standard state. It would appear necessary mathematically, however, that these not differ by more than a multiplicative constant, provided the same standard state is being referenced, that is $\lambda_i = \textrm{constant} \times f_i$.

Comment: $the$ $value$ $of$ $absolute$ $potential$ $in$ $the$ $standard$ $state$, you mean the value of absolute activity in the standard state? Constant you mentioned is equal to $\frac {\lambda_i ^⦵} {f_i ^⦵}$. Absolute activity and fugacity will thus be equal only if: $\lambda_i ^⦵ = f_i ^⦵ $.

Comment: I have one problem. Absolute activity should be independent on the standard state. That is the main motivation for using it. However, we previously saw that: $$\lambda_i = \frac {\lambda_i ^⦵} {f_i ^⦵} f_i$$

Both $\lambda_i ^⦵$ and $f_i ^⦵$ will depend on what standard state is. So, for absolute activity to be independent on standard state, we need to prove that $\frac {\lambda_i ^⦵} {f_i ^⦵}$ is a constant regardless of what standard state is chosen. I'm not sure I can prove this and I don't see why this would necessarily be the case.

Comment: @DarioMirić You are right about the statement you point out, I edited that. I also agree with your definition of the constant . I *don't think* the absolute activity lets you avoid defining a standard state (call it a reference state instead if you prefer). It just makes the equation more compact.

Comment: Although the point I suppose is that a reference value of the absolute activity can be defined without defining an associated standard state (a specific ideal physical condition). (edit: no, that doesn't seem right; in fact it seems again that all you do is simplify the equation by multiplying the fugacity by a constant)

Comment: Yes, while I'm okay that the standard state needs to be defined (which means that absolute activity isn't really absolute), I'm not okay that in the textbook Electrochemical Systems, author claims that absolute activity can be defined without it. Some corrections are required in this textbook. It seems that @MetalStorm was correct about electrochemistry textbooks largely not being very accurate in using concepts from thermodynamics.